Postfix: Delay between individual messages
I need to have a delay between individual messages on my postfix server.
There is a way with default_destination_rate_delay, but there is a minimal value of 1 second.
Is there any way to make it less?
There is no option to increase number of postfix servers or go multi-instance for now, unfortunately.
The problem is that i have to send large amount of messages, but doing it over short period of time makes some providers to blacklist or throttle me

Well, you can implement a policy service that emulates the delay, for that and call that service from check_policy_service in appropriate smtpd_*_restrictions; which one, depends on the exact goal. Remind me, what it was? Because the email technology is definitely not supposed to work with sub-second accuracy. Most likely you're doing something wrong if you need this, and the question looks like XY problem.

The problem is that i have to send large amount of messages, but doing it over short period of time makes some providers to blacklist or throttle me.
I am aware that adding more servers or going multi-instance solves this problem, but this is not an option for now.

The default_destination_rate_delay setting in Postfix has a minimum value of 1 second, and there's no built-in way to go lower.
If you need sub-second delays, we’d have to modify the Postfix source code, but this means building and maintaining a custom version of Postfix.
Alternatively, you could use an external message queue like RabbitMQ or Redis to control delays before messages hit Postfix.
Another option is to implement rate limiting at the network level with tools like iptables or tc. Also, tuning the smtp_destination_concurrency setting can help by limiting the number of concurrent connections Postfix makes to each destination.

Thanks for your reply!
Thats a bummer. There are already a queue manager between my service and postfix, but i'm not ready to make changes to it right now.
Thanks for reminding me about iptables though. This option completely went over my head!
